# I need to get my number to print out in binary for mips. This number is a sum that was calculated. My code isn't working

Tags: printing, binary, numbers, mips, mask

```
.data 
prompt:.asciiz "\nEnter an integer: " 
add: .asciiz "\n The sum in decimal is: "
bin: .asciiz "\n The sum in binary is: "
sgt: .asciiz "\n The second integer is greater than the first. "
fgt: .asciiz "\n The first integer is greater than the second."
equal: .asciiz "\n The two entered values are equal: "

.text

main:

li $v0, 4 #print string code
la $a0, prompt #argument
syscall #execute, service print stri

li $v0, 5 # read integer
syscall #v0 gets the returned value
move $s0, $v0 #set v0 -> s0

li $v0, 4 
la $a0, prompt
syscall

li $v0, 5
syscall
move $s1, $v0 #set v0 -> s1
add  $s2, $s1, $s0 #s2 -> s0 + s1

li $v0, 4 #print string
la $a0, add #argument
syscall 

move $a0, $s2
li $v0, 1 #print int
syscall

# Output "sum in binary is:".  
la $a0, bin
li $v0, 4
syscall


# Output the binary number.  (This is done by isolating one bit
# at a time, adding it to the ASCII code for '0', and outputting
# the character.  It is important that the bits are output in
# most-to-least significant bit order.
move $t2, $a0
li $s1, 32         # Set up a loop counter
Loop:
    rol $t2, $t2, 1    # Roll the bits left by one bit - wraps highest bit to lowest bit.
    and $t0, $t2, 1    # Mask off low bit (logical AND with 000...0001)
    add $t0, $t0, 48   # Combine it with ASCII code for '0', becomes 0 or 1 

    move $a0, $t0      # Output the ASCII character
    li $v0, 11
    syscall

    subi $s1, $s1, 1   # Decrement loop counter
    bne $s1, $zero, Loop  # Keep looping if loop counter is not zero

slt $t0, $s0, $s1
beq $t0, $0, else
li $v0, 4 
la $a0, sgt
syscall
j jump
else: 
li $v0, 4 
la $a0, fgt 
syscall 

jump:
li $v0, 10 #system call for exit
syscall
```

I'm also having quite a bit of trouble getting "the two inputed digits are equal to work. I tried using the three case scenarios and having three separate labels: to send my code to. But it didn't work. I don't know whats going on.

Comment: Can you clean up your formatting somewhat, please. Indent 4 spaces for code blocks, don't use hash marks except in code blocks.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty trivial mistake here.

Look at the line before the loop:

```
move $t2, $a0
```

You are clearly attempting to move the sum into `$t2` but `$a0` contains the address of `bin`.

Changed this line to:

```
move $t2, $s2
```

And everything functions correctly.